# Bind fault domain to specific IP in azure and Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

I want to do these things with teraaform.  I am going to create multiple vms simultaneously like 10.
And i am going to use static IP option.
so let's say my IP is starting with

192.168.5.4, 192.168.5.5, 192.168.5.6 .... so on

so i want to make sure below ip should go in same fault domain.

say fault domain 0

192.168.5.4

192.168.5.7

192.168.5.10

say fault domain 1

192.168.5.5

192.168.5.8

192.168.5.11

say fault domain 2

192.168.5.6

192.168.5.9

192.168.5.12

Relation is (lastnumber % 3) is same. 
how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [simple math interpolation](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#math) with something like this:

```
variable "count" {
  default = 10
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "test" {
    name = "${format("VM%02d-NIC1", count.index + 1)}"
    location = "West US"
    resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
    count = "${var.count}"

    ip_configuration {
        name = "${format("ipConfig-VM%02d-NIC1", count.index + 1)}"
        subnet_id = "SubNet"
        private_ip_address_allocation = "Static"
        private_ip_address = "192.168.5.${count.index + 1}"
    }

    tags {
        fault_domain = "${(count.index + 1) % 3}"
    }
}
```

Then create the rest of the infrastructure according to your requirements and assign the NIC to your VMs:

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "test" {
    count = "${var.count}"
    name = "${format("VM%02-test", cound.index + 1)}"
    location = "West US"
    resource_group_name = "myResourceGroup"
    network_interface_ids = ["${element(azurerm_network_interface.test, count.index).id}"]
    vm_size = "Standard_A0"
    ...
 }
```